# learning Python the hard way argv and file

Tags: python, file, argv, filehandle

I am learning python from past weeks

```
from sys import argv
script,filename = argv 
print "We're delete the file %r" %filename
print "If you want to stop ctrl+c (^c)"
print "Please hit enter to continue"
raw_input(">_")
print "Opening file..."
filen = open(filename,'w')
print "Truncating your file...."
filen.truncate()
print "now in your file %r" %filen
print "Writing time write  something to your file"

line = raw_input("?")
print "write in progress..."
filen.write(line)
filen.write("\n end of document\n")
filen.close()
```

I want to view the contents of the file ,but when i use `print filename` or `print filen` it show name and open file on variable `filen`

Comment: What's with the dollar signs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can read data using `filen.read()` or `filen.readline()` or `filen.readlines()`

1) read

```
fo = open(filename,read)
fo.seek(0, 0) #seek is used to change the file position.This requires only for read method
fo.read(10) #This reads 1st 10 characters
fo.close()
```

2) readline

```
fo = open(filename,read)
fo.readline() #This will read a single line from the file. You can add for loop to iterate all the data
fo.close()
```

3) readlines.

```
fo = open(filename,read)
fo.readline() #read all the lines of a file in a list 
fo.close()
```

Below document will give you better idea.
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: If you're writing first you'll want to [`.seek(0)`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) before reading

Comment: I added "$print filen.read()  " I got IOError: File not open for reading so I ve added "$open(filen,'r') " but this time i got >>    open(filen,'r')
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the content of the file you opened, just use: `print filen.read()`.

Comment: I added "$print filen.read()  " I got IOError: File not open for reading so I ve added "$open(filen,'r') " but this time i got >>    open(filen,'r')
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found

Comment: For that you need to first open the file:
`filen=open(filename, 'r')` and only then use:
`print filen.read()`

Answer (score 0):

At its simplest:

```
from sys import argv
script,filename = argv 
with open(filename) as f:
    print f.readlines()
```

which dumps the files contents
or:

```
from sys import argv
script,filename = argv 
with open(filename) as f:
    lines=f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    print line
```

which prints the lines out 1 by 1